# javascript addClass running but rollback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want addClass in my button, bootstrap.css active.
but by debugging say it work, and soon addClass('active') is rollback.
does anyone know about this problem?
here is my code.

```
$("#a #b button").click(function (){
    if($(this).hasClass("active") == true) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

and this my html

```
<form id="a">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group" id="b">
            <button ...></button>
            <button ...></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

talking again, the problem is not about 'WORKING addClass', addClass do there work, but in passing some parts of jQuery, the class 'active' is disappeared.
anyone please help me.

Comment: Is it possible to share the code you are working with? It would help us have a great starting point for you.

Comment: Add a screenshot of debugger and if required, we let you know. Then you should add the code too.  After adding, mention me here and I will consider reversing the vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find it.
the problem is data-toggle. the data-toggle is working end of addClass, so class is adding but data-toggle doing this roll-back.

the data-toggle is location in div, btn-group.
thx for all adviser.

but still question is it working well in my pc web site.
the problem is occur only access on mobile.